# Accessing sub assembly of an assembly will generate EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, typhoon

Use case:

I have an ApplicationAssembly. This assembly has a property called CoreAssembly of type TyphoonAssembly. I'm using PLIST integration and have registered both Assemblies. I'm injecting the ApplicationAssembly into the Appdelegate.

Afterwads in a ViewController, I want to get an object which will be generated by CoreAssembly

```
    var appdelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as!  AppDelegate;
  tagHandler = appdelegate.assembly.coreAssembly.tagHandler() as! GoogleTagsHandler;
```

If I do this, I get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a bug, we've [logged it](https://github.com/appsquickly/Typhoon/issues/392). In the meantime, as a workaround, please inject both ApplicationAssembly and CoreAssembly into your app delegate as follows:

```
public dynamic func appDelegate() -> AnyObject {
    return TyphoonDefinition.withClass(AppDelegate.self) {
        (definition) in

        definition.injectProperty("assembly", with: self)
        definition.injectProperty("coreAssembly", with: self)
    }
}
```

Comment: I can confirm that the workaround works :). Thanks for the quick response